# Extracting Data from http://www.ign.com/tv/reviews

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I attempted to achieve the following result:
[image]
My code, that currently is not working, is appended

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.ign.com/tv/reviews')
c=r.text
# print(c)
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')

x=soup.find_all('div', class_='item-title')
for item in x:
    print(item)
    print('--------------------------------------------------')
lobbying = {} 
for element in x:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}

#print (lobbying)  # This is a dictionary object
for key,value in lobbying.items(): 
    print(key,value)
for element in x:
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = element.a["href"]

for key,value in lobbying.items(): 
    print(key,value, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
```

This is for first finding the date and score and the inserting the what we find into the  dictionary.

```
f = soup.find_all('div', class_='itemList-item')
reviewItems ={}

for item in f:
    score = item.find("span", class_="scoreBox-scorePhrase").getText()
    date = item.find_all("div", class_="grid_3")[1].getText().strip()
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["score"] = score
    lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["date"] = date

for key,value in lobbying.items(): 
    print(key,value)
```

Comment: So was the actual problem with dates or scores or both? You first talk about dates in URL:s but your code is about scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the info you needed of the items with following:

```
f = soup.find_all('div', class_='itemList-item')

reviewItems = {}

for item in f:
    review = {}
    review["score"] = item.find("span", class_="scoreBox-scorePhrase").getText()
    review["date"] = item.find_all("div", class_="grid_3")[1].getText().strip()
    review["link"] = item.find("a", class_="scoreBox-link")["href"]
    reviewItems[item.find("div", class_="item-title").getText().strip()] = review

for key, value in reviewItems.items():
    print(key, value)
```

If the class you are using is too generic (like the `grid_3`), try finding a more specific one. In this case it is `scoreBox`, or `itemList-item`.

You said you want to get the date from the URL, but I think you meant that you want to get it from the `div` that has it. Seems to be that in this particular case you can just take the second element from the `grid_3` elements found for each itemList-item.

Anyway, this will print out the following for 25 items.

> Ash vs Evil Dead - Home Again {'link': 'http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/04/ash-vs-evil-dead-home-again-review', 'date': 'December 5, 2016', 'score': 'Amazing'}

Comment: Thank you for helping me find the date. But, I need to insert the information you gave me with each url link which I have as dictionary. I have been able to do it , but it does not get inserted into all of them only some of them.                                                                                                                                      DC's Legends of Tomorrow - Invasion!             {'link': 'http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/12/01/dcs-legends-of-tomorrow-invasion-review'}

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want. I assume it has something to do with the `lobbying` variable? Could you edit your question to include the part of the code where you try to insert them? And also the result that where it gets inserted and where not.

Comment: Thank you for helping me find the date. But, I need to insert the information you gave me with each url link which I have as dictionary. I have been able to do it , but it does not get inserted into all of them .        I have a uploaded a picture as an example. The one highlighted as yellow is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please, Look at the picture

'Result I am trying to achieve'                                                                                                                                   Thank you for all your help

Comment: Sooo do I understand correctly that the picture you linked is the desired _output_  of your script?

Comment: Well, now your question is all messed up so you should re-edit it to correct the formatting. I have updated my answer to produce an output that is somewhat similar to your picture.

Comment: 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' error

Comment: If it still does not work, I will create another post with clear question and better coding.

Comment: Just one question,  i am trying to print both date and score on a seperate new line. How would I do that?

Comment: Hm? `print(value['score'])` and `print(value['date'])`I suppose. I'd suggest you to look up some basic dictionary tutorials, that is kinda basic stuff..